# Can the Busybox init start a process as unprivileged user

Tags: busybox, busybox-init

I have a tiny, tiny system comprised of Busybox, an executable application and its dependent libraries ONLY. I am using the Busybox `/etc/inittab` to start the application as an unprivileged user:

```
::sysinit:/sbin/ifup -a -f
::respawn:/bin/busybox su unpriv-user -s /bin/sh -c 'my-executable --arg val --arg val'
```

The system has nothing else, and I don't want to install anything else. Is there a better way to instruct the Busybox inittab to start a process as a given user, or is using `su` like I have the correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`su` seems to be the correct way of doing this - at least according to their mailing list: http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2006-January/052015.html